# jQuery の DataTabales で全データを取得してページングする方法について

Tags: javascript, jquery

タイトル通りで jQuery の DataTabales で全データを取得してページングする方法についてご教授ください。
表示するデータはAjaxでサーバから取得しているのですが、今はページングするたびにAjaxで次ページの情報を取得する動きとなっています。

マニュアルのオプションを一通り見てみましたが自分では見つけられませんでした。
https://datatables.net/reference/option/

現在調査した結果として下記のように推測しています。

pageLength オプションを -1 とすることで全データを取得できましたがページングが有効となりませんでした。

このことから pageLength の値を Ajax リクエストの情報に載せて DB の select に対する limit と、1ページに表示するレコード数を制御していると考えています。

なのでページのレコード数の制御と、Ajaxのリクエスト情報を別々に制御できればよいのではないかと考えているのですが、制御する方法がわかりません。

なにか情報がありましたらご教授いただきたく思います。

---

補足：サーバサイドのDB操作は Ignited-Datatables というライブラリを利用しています。
https://github.com/IgnitedDatatables/Ignited-Datatables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ページングするたびにリクエストが走るのは bServerSide というオプションが設定されていたためでした。
これを false とすることで全データを取得することができました。
ただ全データ取得では取得数が大量にあると処理が重くなるのでいろいろと考えることがありそうです。
本質問としてはクローズいたします。